# Cron Expression Quartz in spring configuration

Tags: spring, cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I need a cron expression for fire event at 8,18,28 of every month. I put into bean

```
 <bean id="scartiJobTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="scartiJobLauncher"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="??????????????????????"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**0 0 12 8,18,28 * ?**
fires at 12 PM for every month of specified days.
You can find detailed information here [quartz cron expresssion](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)